# how to search git log without a certain commit

Tags: regex, git, git-log

Assume I have a branch master with 3 commits, the comments are t123, b1 and b12 separately.

```
* b90b03f (HEAD -> master) b12
* 27f7577 b1
* 7268b40 t123
```

And now, I want to use `git log --grep <regex>` to search the log log without t123.
The result I want is

```
* b90b03f b12
* 27f7577 b1
```

So how do I use regex to meet the requirement?

Comment: add `--invert-grep`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like what you want is to include all commits whose commit messages *do not* match some pattern, but `--grep` includes commits that *do* match some pattern.  But the answer to "how do I write a regexp that matches everything *except* some pattern" is: You don't.<sup>1</sup>

You don't need to, because you can use *something else* (or more precisely, something additional) to exclude the commit with the string "t123" in it.  Specifically, if you look at [the documentation for `git log`](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-log.html), you will find that it not only has its `--grep=<pattern>` option, but also an `--invert-grep` option:

> `--invert-grep`
>          Limit the commits output to ones with log message that do not match
>              the pattern specified with **`--grep=<pattern>`**.

That is, instead of inventing some sort of inverse regular expression, you simply tell the command to invert the *result* from *searching* for the regular expression.  Since your regexp is just a fixed string with no meta-characters in it:

```
git log --grep t123 --invert-grep
```

will do the job.  (The `=` between `--grep` and the `<pattern>` part is optional for `--grep`.)

---

<sup>1</sup>It is, in some sense, not impossible; it's just way too difficult, inefficient, and most of all, unnecessary.

Comment: If you have the same problem in another context, you can write an inverted expression, example: `[^t]|t[^1]|t1[^2]|t12[^3]`, this would match anything but `t123`

Comment: @lmcarreiro: that doesn't quite work, because if we have `foo t123` for instance, the `[^t]` alternative will match `f`.  In fact, if we have just `t123` and regular-expression-search for this, it will match because `[^t]` matches `1`! To make this work you need an *anchored* regexp—or, again, just simplify the entire problem away with inversion (this is why `grep` has `-v` for instance).